When using cosign keyless, how can you view the Rekor URL entry based on the cosign bundle?
Sigstore Cosign can be used to sign a blob and output a bundle.
cosign sign-blob test.txt --bundle test.txt.cosign.bundle

Now, given this bundle, how can you view or derive the Rekor URL entry?
An example of an entry is
https://rekor.sigstore.dev/api/v1/log/entries/24296fb24b8ad77a7e53fd5d089af142b7909598d214e13ca76001cc575fddaad3210adbee86363e

The bundle file is a JSON file and has fields such as base64Signature, cert, SignedEntryTimestamp, integratedTime, logIndex, logID.  However, none of these were substitute-able in the above URL, which makes me wonder if the entry URL can somehow be derived from the values available in the bundle.

Alright I had to dig a lot and I think I have the answer. You can use the logIndex in a bundle to search for the Rekor entry.
In the example I've posted, the logIndex is 25579.
The Rekor URL is:
https://rekor.sigstore.dev/api/v1/log/entries?logIndex=25579

Which has the same contents as:
https://rekor.sigstore.dev/api/v1/log/entries/b6fdc91e6af5bdd8df133802b7966aa53c1e59365741ee56e287f11263e02c33

Bash steps from signing to viewing:
# sign the blob
cosign sign-blob test.txt --bundle test.txt.cosign.bundle

# view the logindex
cat test.txt.cosign.bundle  | jq -r '.rekorBundle.Payload.logIndex'

# get the Rekor URL
logindex=$(cat test.txt.cosign.bundle  | jq -r '.rekorBundle.Payload.logIndex')
echo https://rekor.sigstore.dev/api/v1/log/entries?logIndex=$logindex

# view the Rekor contents
curl https://rekor.sigstore.dev/api/v1/log/entries?logIndex=$logindex
xdg-open https://rekor.sigstore.dev/api/v1/log/entries?logIndex=$logindex

